# ccny_rgbd with vo+mapping rosservice call error

Tags: navigation, mapping, ccny-rgbd, rosservice, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Dryanovski and fellow campaigners,

I am using ROS Groovy on an i3 laptop and ATI 6770m. I use your ccny package. Nearly everything works fine. I can start all launch files an see the rgbd screen (Topic: /rgbd/cloud) in rviz. Just one problem: I want to see the whole map in rviz, but it disappears. I think i must call the service
rosservice call /publish_keyframes ".*" to publish all keyframes an set the delay time unequal zero. But i get just the error message after the call:

ERROR: service [/publish_keyframes] responded with an error:

nothing else :(
In rviz i can set the topic to "keyframes", but no pointcloud!

I tried different detector types and change their params...no effect...

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

rossi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65725/ccny_rgbd-with-vo+mapping-rosservice-call-error/) by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2013-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

The keyframes are not published on `rgbd/cloud`, but on `keyframes` instead. I'm not sure why the error is occurring. Can you visualize the keyframes in rviz without the service?

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2013-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rossi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4597/rossi/) on 2013-07-02**:\